# Returning JSON response from Rest service?

Tags: java, rest, web-services

I have developed a RESTful webservice and it has a POST method.

I need to return `json` response. Can I have my post method return type void and set the `json` string in `httpresponse` body?

**OR**

Do I need return the `JSON` string by changing the method return type to String? Which one is recommended? Please guide me...

Thanks!

Comment: well, there are lots of ways, and they mostly depend from libraries you use for rest, maybe you can post some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can change the return Type of doPost to void:

```
/**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String value = value; //JSON value you want to return
            StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
            out.append("{\"key\": \"" + value+ "\"}");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.getWriter().write(out.toString());
    }
```